# Recursive function to find a specific ID tag on a website

Tags: html, excel, vba, recursion

I am trying to recursively find a specific ID on a website.

The code crashes without an error message. If I go step by step it is no problem (even if it did not find the id). I think the exit condition is correct and it is not an endless loop.

```
Public Function SetRecursiveInputFieldbyID(ByRef IE As Object, ByRef prevNode As Variant, _
  ByRef ident As String) As Boolean
'    On Error GoTo error

    For Each t In prevNode.Document.ChildNodes
        If t.ID = ident Then
            Debug.Print "Found"
            SetRecursiveInputFieldbyID = True
            Exit For
        ElseIf t.ChildNodes.length <> 0 Then
            If t.ID <> "" Then Debug.Print t.ID
            If SetRecursiveInputFieldbyID(IE, t, ident) Then
                SetRecursiveInputFieldbyID = True
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next t
    Exit Function

'error:
'    SetRecursiveInputFieldbyID = False
End Function
```

After removing `On Error GoTo error` I see the error is

> "out of stack space"

Comment: Remove your `On Error GoTo error` statement, in surpresses error messages. An educated guess on my part would be that your `.Document` is not loaded in time for the code to work on.

Comment: Why is `IE` passed?  Doesn't `prevNode.Document` remain constant as the `document` or are you loading different pages?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I load different pages with the same module and some are intranet and some are external so I have to use different IE Objects

Comment: @Nacorid good call now I get a "out of stack space" error :) now I can fix this I hope

Comment: why are you using recursion to find an id? Also, can you share the url?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the need for the complexity and overhead of recursion. Why not simply attempt to match a node on id and test if anything was set? You might additionally want to add a timed loop testing for presence of matched node to cater for slowly loading pages.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer, ids(), i As Long

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ids = Array("footer", "banana")

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://stackoverflow.com/"

        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

        For i = LBound(ids) To UBound(ids)

            If IdFound(.document, ids(i)) Then Debug.Print ids(i), vbTab, "Found"

        Next
        Stop
        '.Quit
    End With
End Sub

Public Function IdFound(ByVal document As htmlDocument, ByVal ident As String) As Boolean
    Dim node As Object
    Set node = document.querySelector("#" & ident & "")
    IdFound = Not node Is Nothing
End Function
```

---

**References:**

1. Requires reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library via VBE>Tools>References

Comment: Did you try this?